# How to Count/Sum a Column depending on a value of another Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table that tracks time:

```
  A     B           C               D           E
1 Time  Duration    Activity        Category    Work Type
2 06:30 01:00       Morning Routine Maintenance No
3 07:30 06:00       Commute         Idle        No
4 13:30 02:00       Task 1          Marketing   Strategic Work
5 15:30 00:20       Task 2          Branding    Strategic Work
6 15:50 02:40       Task 3          Sidequests  Tactical Work
7 18:30 01:00       Fitness         Maintenance No
8 19:30 02:30       Reddit          Idle        No
9 22:00
```

I want to count the duration of all the "Strategic Work" of the day.

I tried something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E9;"Strategic Work")
```

But obviously this just counts the times "Strategic Work" appears, and not the duration.

Then I tried this direction:

```
=SUMIF(E2:E9;"Strategic Work";B2:B9)
```

But it outputs: `0.097222222`, instead of `02:20`, which is the correct answer.

How do I count the duration, if the Work Type is "Strategic Work"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct. You only have to format your output as time. `0.097222222` is the decimal representation of the duration `02:20`.